# Implementing “Report this content” against postings only for unique users

Tags: report, ip-address

I've seen the following Question : [Implementing "Report this content" and detecting spammer or robot triggered event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176795/implementing-report-this-content-and-detecting-spammer-or-robot-triggered-even), but it doesn't quite answer all I need to know about setting up a "Report this content" function.

My situation is very similar (users not needing to login to be able to report content) but I'm unsure what I should capture about a user to ensure that they are not reporting a single posting multiple times.

I thought the most obvious one would be IP address but I heard that mobile users can sometimes find themselves all sharing a single IP address when the users are close together.

This means I need something else as well.

The Question above mentions user-agent but it doesn't sound too far fetched that multiple iPhone users could be sharing the same IP address, so even with IP address and user-agent it still isn't unique.

What if I logged their IP address and their session ID?

Would that be a good compromise or can anyone suggest a better option?

Thanks